Would it be beneficial for me to open a savings account with a bank or credit union from which I plan to obtain a mortgage?
As a first-time homebuyer with limited information or experience in the field, I'm planning to purchase my first home in winter 2024 or spring 2025. Currently, I have approximately $50,000 in my checking account, and I intend to increase this amount to $100,000 to $150,000 by then. I'm curious if there are any banks, credit unions, or special programs where transferring my funds could potentially ease the process of qualifying for a home mortgage or secure a more favorable deal?
P.S.: I plan to opt for a conventional loan with a 10-20% down payment, but I'm unsure if there are any better opportunities available for first-time homebuyers?
P.S.: I plan to buy a single family house in San Francisco Bay area.

Some banks give relationship discounts, but they are based on the amounts left at the bank after closing, if you store the downpayment there they wouldn't take that into account.


I'm curious if there are any banks, credit unions, or special programs
where transferring my funds could potentially ease the process of
qualifying for a home mortgage or secure a more favorable deal?

Many credit unions will not give loans to non-members. You would have to check on how long you must have funds deposited in the credit union before they will give you a loan.

Currently, I have approximately $50,000 in my checking account, and I
intend to increase this amount to $100,000 to $150,000 by then.

While it is good that you don't have the money you are saving for a down payment invested in the stock market,  make sure that you are getting some interest on those funds. It would seem to be easy to get 4 or 5% via a high interest account, CD or even Treasury bills.
The problem you will have is that the financial institution with the best deal today, might not be the best one a year from now. You could move your funds and then never get a loan from that bank.

I plan to opt for a conventional loan with a 10-20% down payment, but
I'm unsure if there are any better opportunities available for
first-time homebuyers?

Sometime the state or a city might have a first time home buyer program. You will have to see what it takes to qualify regarding income, down payment; and what interest rate reduction is available.
